# JMETER 4.0 using IF controller and a global variable

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I'm a newbie in JMETER .
I'm asked by to run a data using 0 & 1 in the below format.
These are example threads
1.ABC save 
2.123 save as well as ABC save
3.Should not run both the save threads.
 All these should be done using Single IF controller and a global variable

Comment: Please share what you have done till now or your plan in order to get faster response.

Comment: I have used two IF controller with the following expression for each ${__jexl3(${VAR}==1)} and for other ${__jexl3(${VAR}==0)}  and in the User Defined Variable i have added the value Name: VAR & Value:1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below snapshots.

1. User Defined Variable for global setting
   [image]
2. If to control the execution. All samplers below this controller.
   [image]

Now,  if you change user defined variable to 0 or 1, then it will execute based on the rule. No need to have two if controller.

Hope this help.

Update:-

In user defined variables, add name of sampler
[image]

Pass parameter to switch and second sampler under switch.
[image]

Now, second will only run if the user defined variable is matching with the sampler name, if you change it two some other in user defined variable then it will not run. For more check [switch controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But if i put both the samplers under the if controller with user defined variable 0, both the samplers will be executed .But i want justone sampler to be executed when the value is 0 and the other sampler should not execute

Comment: Use two if and one sampler each. First if condition ${__jexl3(${switch} == 0)} and second if condition ${__jexl3(${switch} == 1)}..Now, only one will execute...You can also use switch two run one based on a switch value..Check the update.